# Where can I find an updated Google filter Greasmonkey script?

Tags: greasemonkey, google-search

Recently, Google updated their search results page.  Unfortunately, this broke pretty much every Greasemonkey script used on the results page, including the very useful filter scripts.  I use these scripts at work when I encounter a coding problem that (for some reason) hasn't been answered at StackOverflow, and don't want to see sites like experts-exchange.  Has anyone found a new script or updated their own to work with Google's new results page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't, but when one is available then you'll be able to find it at [userscripts.org (us.o)](http://userscripts.org/) I'm sure. If you look at [the us.o page for the 'google' tag](http://userscripts.org/tags/google) (which is sorted by 'last updated by default) you should find all of the scripts that update the Google search engine page results (SERP), and there is [a Google group on us.o](http://userscripts.org/groups/9/scripts) where ppl can maintain a collection of Google related userscripts and discuss Google userscripts.

If you can't find the userscript that does what you want and works, then you can either start a discuss with an author of a script that doesn't work, tag the userscript as having an issue and describe the issue, [request someone make a userscript that does what you want here](http://userscripts.org/forums/2), or get help making a userscript your self [here](http://userscripts.org/forums/1) and/or [here](http://groups.google.com/group/greasemonkey-users).

Answer (score 1):

Check out this script http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/79742.  It seems to work for me, however you first need to edit it and change .tld to your proper google page.