# Exclude specific sites or urls from Google search results?

Tags: google-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible with Google searches to ban any and all results from a domain?](https://superuser.com/questions/5631/is-it-possible-with-google-searches-to-ban-any-and-all-results-from-a-domain)

When searching google a few sites constantly show up in my search results.  However, these sites are never relevant to me.  Is there a way to blacklist sites by domain, regular expression or other method?  Preferably I would like to do this prior to any searching and not in the search string each time I need to Google something.

Each time I come across a new site that is spammy or otherwise not relevant I would like to be able to easily add it to the blacklist.

I use a mixture of Google Chrome and FireFox on MacOSX Snow Leopard.  I am not opposed to using plugins if there aren't any settings that can be applied to the Google search engine itself.

Comment: I found a way to completely remove sites from google search results, via a page on Google itself. You must have a google account for it to work: http://www.google.com/reviews/t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grease Monkey for Firefox is going to be the best place to start, as partially documented [here](https://superuser.com/questions/147360/where-can-i-find-an-updated-google-filter-greasmonkey-script).  [This](http://blog.arpitnext.com/2009/09/use-run-greasemonkey-scripts-in-google-chrome.html) is where you can find how to get those scripts running under Chrome.

Unfortunately, Google changed how they format the results page, and it broke a bunch of scripts, and I haven't seen any that now work.