# How can I permanently suppress sites from Google search results?

Tags: search

I stay logged into Google. I would very much like to permanently blacklist sites that I know to be spammy or low quality from showing up in some of the modules like news and search. Any suggestions on how? I know how to do it case by case in search (`-site:lame.example.com`) but that's not permanent.

EDIT: The solution presented below (Personal Blocklist) does in fact work for search (thanks!) but not for news - anyone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible with Google searches to ban any and all results from a domain?](http://superuser.com/questions/5631/is-it-possible-with-google-searches-to-ban-any-and-all-results-from-a-domain), [Exclude specific sites or urls from Google search results?](http://superuser.com/questions/191999/exclude-specific-sites-or-urls-from-google-search-results)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update 2022-06:** This no longer works and there is no native replacement or Extension/App by Google.

If you use Chrome you can use [Personal Blocklist (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef?hl=en).

> **Description**
>
> Blocks domains/hosts from appearing in your Google search results.
>
> The personal blocklist extension will transmit to Google the patterns
> that you choose to block.

This use to be a standard feature on Google that they depreciated. Instead they created this extension.

Comment: This works with Google search, I have not tested the news module.

Comment: It doesn't work for News but it does work for search.

Comment: No longer works

Comment: This no longer works as of 
Version 102.0.5005.63. Moderators: please remove this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use Adblocker, then remove all the preset blacklists, then manually blocking those websites/span ID's?

Comment: Thanks. I do adblock but that doesn't affect the list of results that G shows for searches nor in news etc.